# How to understand this in perl

Tags: perl

```
my @skipper = qw(blue_shirt hat jacket preserver sunscreen);
my @skipper_with_name = ('The Skipper' => \@skipper);
```

How to understand the second line?

```
print @skipper_with_name;
```

got the following msg:

```
The SkipperARRAY(0x209cf90)
```

Comment: Welcome to `SO`! If you want to say `thank you` somebody, you may upvote his answer. If you want to say `great thanks! it is really helpful and it solve my problem, you are wizard`, you may accept his answer - press green stick which placed under vote-arrows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stevenl mentions, `Data::Dumper` only prints out the structure of array or hash, if you pass a reference into it, not the structure itself. Otherwise it prints what the structure is `(ARRAY)` and its memory address.

Also, if you are expecting `@skipper_with_name` to be a `HASH` and not an `ARRAY`, I will point out that `@` is only used for arrays, `%` is the symbol for a `HASH` (so it would be `%skipper_with_name`). Also, although `=>` is most commonly used in hashes to show the key/value relationship, it is essentially just a comma, so can be used without error to create an array.

```
my @skipper_with_name = ('The Skipper' => \@skipper);
```

is the same as:

```
my @skipper_with_name = ('The Skipper',  \@skipper);
```

you can see here:

```
 $skipper_with_name[0] = 'The Skipper' 
 $skipper_with_name[1] = \@skipper
```

Comment: `=>` is not a `realationship` operator or something else. it is beautiful lazy operator: The `=>` operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores

Comment: Spot on loldop, I didn't mean the => operator actually defines the relationship, only that people use it that way, by convention, to improve readability. As you say, it is synonymous with a comma.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash in front of `@skipper` gets the reference to the array.

You can see the actual structure if you:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@skipper_with_name;
```

Perhaps you wanted a hash instead for the second array, which means that `The Skipper` can be used as a key for accessing `@skipper`:

```
my %skipper_with_name = ('The Skipper' => \@skipper);
print Dumper \%skipper_with_name;
my @skipper_copy = @{$skipper_with_name{'The Skipper'}};
```

Note how I've used `@{...}` to dereference the array reference.

Comment: very-very-very difficult to understand for beginners

Answer (score 1):

It's a new Array which has a reference (the slash in front of the array `\`) to your initial array stored in it. If you print it, you only get the memory address, you need to dereference it first by again prepending the `@` symbol to get the content of the hash.

However this makes no real sense, Arrays can only have numeric indixes. What you probably want to do is to use a hash.

```
my %skipper_with_name = ('The Skipper' => \@skipper);
```

now you can reference to the array via the `'The Skipper'` identifier.

```
print Dumper $skipper_with_name{'The Skipper'};
#or
print @{ $skipper_with_name{'The Skipper'} };
```